# Vba code for how to group together numbers which are the 31st character in a string with a row break between consecutive numbers

Tags: string, excel, vba

I'm trying to edit my code so that it groups all of the same numbers in a string together and adds a row break between it and the consecutive number so that it is easier to read.

The number I want is always the 31st character in a string and I want the data to display so that this 31st character is grouped together. Any help would be appreciated, my current code is:

```
Sub CopyMatchedValuesToSheet()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRowSource As Long, i As Long
Dim SearchString As String
Dim cell As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("effect00001")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

SearchString = "(9)" ' Set SearchString value or use the one below if you want to change it each time

'SearchString = Application.InputBox("Give a string", "SearchString", Type:=2)

i = 1

With ws1
    LastRowSource = .Cells.find("(9)", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    For Each cell In .Range("A1:A" & LastRowSource) ' Change to A2 if it has header
        If InStr(cell.Value, SearchString) > 0 Then
            ws2.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = cell.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Function ChopOutChar(s as string)

 Dim thirtyfirst as string
 thirtyFirst = mid(s,31,1)
 thirtyfirst = thirtyfirst &  vbcrlf ' "Carriage Return/LineFeed"
 ChopOUtChar = thirtyfirst
End Function
```